# In orgmode, how to add html attributes to a link inside a header?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, org-link

I can add attributes to links like this:

```
#+attr_html: :rel external :target _blank
[[http://www.wikipedia.com][reliable source]]
```

Now, I have a link in a header:

```
* DONE Why people talk [[http://www.wikipedia.com][(reliable source)]]
```

How do I add the attributes to this link in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

**`Org mode` syntax DOES NOT ALLOW one to apply attributes to a span of text in the *middle* of a paragraph.  That is, attributes can be added only to the whole paragraph (via `+attr_*:`) and to headlines (via `:PROPERTIES: ... :END:`).**

Well, the previous sentence is a (kind of) lie.

If you define a custom link, you will be able to sneak in additional attributes as part of "custom" link definition.  *(Btw, the moment you define a custom link, it no longer is an `org mode` proper, but your  own custom extension to it)*

Roll your own custom link type, or see if there are existing link types that do what you want in [NonGNU ELPA - org-contrib](https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/org-contrib.html).

See the bottom of

```lisp
(info "(org) External Links")
```

specifically the following link

```lisp
(info "(org) Adding Hyperlink Types")
```

- [External Links (The Org Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/External-Links.html)
- [Adding Hyperlink Types (The Org Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Adding-Hyperlink-Types.html)